# task analysis in design thinking

Tags: design-thinking

I'm using a design thinking framework to develop a new mobile application.

[image]

In which phase of design thinking is collocated hierarchical task analysis?

Answer (score 1):

That's really hard to tell based on this diagram, as the keywords aren't that clearly defined. Could you point to some resources for this particular design framework?

In any case, if you were to create an HTA, it would be in a phase after conducting and analyzing your research but before ideating. I have no clue what "point of view" is supposed to represent in this case, but as it's after observation and before ideation, I'm guessing HTA could belong there.